# get the value in the select dropdown using jquery and targeted to the button using click function

Tags: jquery

Hi i have this select dropdown which i want the value to be passed to the button. My select dropdown is queried to the database. I want that when i select one the value will be passed to the button and if i choose two the value will be passed to the  button too. Heres my code below

```
 <select id="profile_family" name="families" class="form-control">  
                        <?php foreach($profile as $p): ?>
                         <option  value="<?php echo $p->id?>"><?php echo $p->profile_type; ?></option>
                         <?php endforeach; ?>
                      </select>
                      <br />
                      <br />
                      <input type="button" id="createBox" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Create profile" />

 $("#createBox").click(function(){
        $('#profile_family').on('change', function() {
            alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
         });
      });
```

can someone help me figured this out? thanks

Comment: `$("#createBox").click(function () {
    var value = $('#profile_family').val();
    alert(value)
});`? when would you want the alert to appear.. when clicking on the button or when changing the value

Comment: when clicking the button the value will alert the value of the select dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$("#createBox").click(function(){
    //$('#profile_family').on('change', function() {
        alert( $('#profile_family').val()); // or $(this).val()
    //});
});
```

Example is [Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/mgmxkz20/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want get the value of the select on button click, try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/p7vwk3eu/)

```
$("#createBox").click(function(){
        alert($('#profile_family').val());
});
```